# Use a nested route for fetching data from the server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'd like to ask a RESTful server for just the `products` of a given `category`. The server has a nested route for both. So the path `/categories/1/products` will export only the products of the `category` with the ID 1.

In my current application I has a route which fetches the first `category` and all `products`. Which is a waste of resources. How can I change it that Ember Data fetches only the `products` of that `category` using the nested path of the server?

**route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      category: this.store.find('category', 1),
      products: this.store.find('product')
    };
  }
});
```

**app/category/model.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  products: DS.hasMany('product', { async: true })
});
```

**app/product/model.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**app/application/adapter.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://www.example.com',
  namespace: 'api/v1',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally do this is via a query string.

```
this.store.query('products', {category : 1});
//for older ember-data version use syntax below
//this.store.fetch('products', {category : 1});
```

This will generate

```
http://www.example.com/api/v1/products?category=1
```

Your server method can select the appropriate products

---

Actually reviewing you question again, you could do the following to avoid any server changes.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      let promise = this.store.find('category', 1);
      category: promise , //mmmm ... this line might not work because I have chained a .then() onto it below, if not try this.store.find('category', 1).  Get back to me with your findings.
      products: promise.then(function(category) {
          return category.get('products').then(function(products) {
              return products;
          });
      });
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the "right" solution, but the OP is hinting that he wants to find a way to work with the existing endpoint definitions.